# Problems using the goo.gl API from google apps script

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script, goo.gl

I'm trying to query the goo.gl API from inside a Google Apps Script. The problem I'm seeing is the following error message:

```
Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXLmGJQw returned code 400. Server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } ], "code": 400, "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } } (line 28)
```

the message comes up when I try to do the actual request at `UrlFetchApp.fetch(post_url, options);`.

Here's the actual coding I'm using in Google Apps Script.

```js
function minifyGoogl(longUrl) {
  var post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url';

  var apiKey = UserProperties.getProperty('googl_api_key');

  if(!apiKey){
    var apiKey = ScriptProperties.getProperty('googl_api_key');
  }

  if(apiKey){
    post_url += '?key=' + apiKey;
  }

  var payload = Utilities.jsonStringify({'longUrl': longUrl });

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    'payload' : payload
  };

  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(post_url, options);
  }catch(e){
    if(e.message){
      throw e.message;
    }
  }

  var responseJson = response.getAs('json');
}
function testMinifyGoogl(){
  minifyGoogl('http://eduardo.cereto.net');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_urlfetchapp.html) says the `contentType` *defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'*.

Perhaps try setting the `Content-Type` with the `contentType` argument rather than inserting a `Content-Type` header manually?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. I didn't see that `contentType` parameter. And tried to set it myself using the HTTP header parameter.

Comment: That fixed it for me. The lib I was using wanted me to manually JSON.stringify my request body. This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly.

```
function ShortenUrl(){
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url';
var apiKey = 'AIzBlNS-3HZdxKgwj-x30';
url += '?key=' + apiKey;
var payload = {"longUrl":"www.google.com"};

var parameters = { method : 'post',
                payload:JSON.stringify(payload),
                contentType:'application/json',                    
                muteHttpExceptions:true};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters);
Logger.log(response);
}
```