# Using google url shortener in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, bit.ly, goo.gl

Here are some examples of shortening multiple urls in google docs.

http://www.lebseodesign.com/2011/04/create-short-urls-using-apis-and-google-docs/

How to accomplish this through Goo.gl shortener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw your post here so am going to answer you here and not on my blog

theres is two methods to use goo.gl shortner. through JSON and it requires you to use an API from your API Console.

Implementation can be done using Google Apps script like this example here [Problems using the goo.gl API from google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566394/problems-using-the-goo-gl-api-from-google-apps-script)

and the documentation to use the api can be found here

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten

Thank you

Comment: url-shortener link no longer works and creating links using url-shortener has been deprecated: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html